# How to update running JobService with new request?

Tags: android, api, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I have an app with the option to download files. For this purpose, I've implemented DownloadService which will firstly do the database query to get download candidates and then build queue for download. Once the queue is built, it will start processing downloads 1 by 1 until the queue is empty and then will finish itself. While service is running user can add more download requests (send ACTION to running service to re-build queue).
But we [can't use background service](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) when targeting Oreo or newer version of Android anymore, and I would like to avoid implementing it as foreground service to avoid displaying notification while determining download queue and not doing actual file download.

I've tried to `schedule` it with `setOverrideDeadline(0)` using `JobScheduler` API but instead of updating running job, the old one was destroyed, and the new one created. I've also tried to `enqueue JobWorkItem` instead, but `onStartJob` of `JobService` (where I am supposed to dequeue work) is not called if the job is already running so I can't update it with new requests.

EDIT 1:
I have an experimental implementation where I will check if my JobService is running using this sample code

```
private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
        if("com.example.MyJobService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If job is not running I will schedule it, but if it is running I will send event to this job using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and update job with new request. But I would prefer 'pure' JobScheduler's API solution.

EDIT 2: I have also option to download multiple files in parallel and to change priority of queued downloads.

Do anybody know how to keep posting new requests (actions) to running job without creating a new one with `JobScheduler` API? (without 3rd party libraries)

Comment: If you are downloading 1 by 1, why do you need to implement your queue? `JobScheduler` already have a queue built in... other than that it, seems a little weird that you need to query `ActivityManager` when you have the `JobService` callbacks (and `JobScheduler. getAllPendingJobs()`)

Comment: @YoniGross I have also option to download multiple files in parallel and to change priority of queued downloads

Comment: @majov Hi, did you managed to find a way to achieve what you wanted?